# MEF: CompositionContainer and part lifetimes & ownership

Tags: .net, mef

I'm trying to wrap my head around part lifetimes and ownership. I get that a shared part will have it's lifetime scoped to the container. But what about non shared instances? It says that the container won't hold references to parts created unless it's shared or implements IDisposable, but it also says that **all** parts created by the container are conditioned to the containers lifetime and the only way to get rid of them is to dispose the container.

So which is it? Does the container hold a reference to ALL parts it creates or only the ones that fit the specific conditions? I'm also confused because it says that the container never transfers ownership of a part it creates. But if it doesn't hold a reference to non shared parts (that aren't implementing IDispoable) then wouldn't it in fact be transfering ownership to the requestor?

Source: http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parts%20Lifetime&referringTitle=Guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objection makes sense when you think of being "alive" in terms of unmanaged languages. For example in C++, any object that is allocated on the heap needs to be freed at some point, and that would be the responsibility of the container. So the container would need to keep a reference to *all* the objects it created, and free them at some point.

However, in the .NET runtime the garbage collector will take care of reclaiming memory. So the container only needs to keep a reference to an instance if it might be reused when handling future requests for parts (i.e. it is *shared*), or if it needs to be disposed at some point.

If neither of these conditions are true, then the concepts of lifetime and ownership can safely be ignored. All that matters is that the object is usable as long as there are references to it, and the garbage collector will make sure of that.

So to answer your question: it keeps references **only to the objects that fit specific conditions**. However, that doesn't mean you can just keep on calling `container.GetExportedValue` and expect no memory leaks. Consider what happens if the non-disposable object which you request has disposable dependencies. The container will still keep references to those!

Therefore, if you want to dynamically create objects via the container, it is best to use `ExportFactory` instead (introduced in .NET 4.5). This way you can re-introduce the concept of "lifetime" even if the object isn't disposable, and the container will make sure to clean up non-shared dependencies when you signal it with `ExportLifetimeContext<T>.Dispose`.